# Which bus providers in South Korea run from Sokcho to Pohang?

Tags: buses, south-korea

I'm trying to book travel from Sokcho-si to Gyeongju, which [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com) suggests taking as a bus trip from Sokcho Express terminal to Pohang and then changing to a local bus from Pohang to Gyeongju.

[image: Sokcho to Pohang bus]

However, when I check the [bus provider's website](https://www.bustago.or.kr/newweb/en/ticket/ticket.do) for this trip, it freezes me after displaying schedule with no option to proceed.

[image: Sokcho to Pohang bus schedule]

Is this the only provider that runs the route? And if yes, am I missing some booking rule (e.g. minimum gap before booking?) since there's an "X" under the "Sale" column?

Comment: My experience with intercity buses in Korea has been that there's no need to book in advance unless it's a peak period or something -- just rock up and buy tickets on the spot. YMMV.

Comment: Rome2Rio is good for getting ideas.  It never shows all possibilities and if is often wrong about schedules and prices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've queried the Sokcho bus terminal from the BusTago in Korean language.

Left is the departure and right side is the destination. You can see two circles in the destinations, which says "Cannot book online: Purchase at the terminal". You cannot purchase a ticket using BusTago on the web.

However, there is another [inter-city bus reservation system operated by T-money](https://txbuse.t-money.co.kr/), so check the route if you can book it online with T-money's interface. Since there is no direct route from Sokcho to Pohang, you will need to book two tickets for each bus. Make sure you allocate enough transfer time to accommodate for unforeseeable incidents.

[image: Screenshot of Bustago]